# Stub a chained void method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm wondering how to stub a void method's actions when the void method is a the last method in a chain of method invocations. For example, we have the following (extremely simplified) classes:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Resource
    private MyDependency myDependency;

    public void put(Item item) {
        myDependency.getDao().putItem(item);
    }
}

public class MyDependency {
    @Getter
    private MyDao myDao;
}

public class MyDao {
    public void putItem(Item item) throws Exception {
        // saves item to database
        // ...
    }
}
```

How do we write a test for the case when a nested dependency throws an exception?

```
@InjectMocks
private MyClass myClass;

@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
private MyDependency injectedMyDependency;

private void stubDependencyException1() throws Exception {
    doThrow(new Exception())
            .when(injectedMyDependency).getDao().putItem(any());
}

private void stubDependencyException2() throws Exception {
    doThrow(new Exception())
            .when(injectedMyDependency.getDao()).putItem(any());
}

private void stubDependencyException3() throws Exception {
    MyDao mockDao = mock(MyDao.class);
    when(injectedMyDependency.getDao()).thenReturn(mockDao);
    doThrow(new Exception()).when(mockDao).putItem(any());
}

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    stubDependencyException1();

    myClass.put(new Item());
}

@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
    stubDependencyException2();

    myClass.put(new Item());
}

@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void test3() throws Exception {
    stubDependencyException3();

    myClass.put(new Item());
}
```

Test 1 - does not work because the getDao() does not throw an exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
```

Test 2 - fails for this reason:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.blah...

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

Test 3 - works, but not as readable as others; does not take advantage of RETURN_DEEP_STUBS.

Is there a different way of stubbing that takes advantage of RETURN_DEEP_STUBS?

Comment: Looks like you're falling victim to the classic tester's pitfall: test everything. If you've already properly unit tested `myDependency.getDao()` and `myDao.putItem()` then you don't need to test all possible cases of `MyClass#put()`. You can rely on the existing tests. You just need to test that `MyClass#put()` meets its unit requirements.

Comment: `MyDepencendy` also has no behavior, its just data. So this shouldn't be mocked in the first place.

Comment: @PaulHicks Part of MyClass#put()'s unit requirements are that it handles a specific exception of downstream dependencies. This case cannot be unit tested in either the MyDependency or MyDao's unit tests, as those unit tests don't test how consumers handle their errors, only that they throw the errors.

That discussion aside, my question is assuming that this test is needed and I can't refactor tests how you're suggesting.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker the actual class does have behavior, but I've simplified it here.

Comment: But if `MyDependency` has behaviour, isn't `myDependency.getDao().putItem(item)` then a violation of the law of demeter?